# How to get unique Topics a user has Commented on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Topic and Comment model one to many.

How can I get all the unique topics a user has commented on.

@comments = current_user.comments will return all the users comments, but if I try to display the topic of each comment, Ill get repeats. I just want the unique topics.

Also I have comments and topics default scope to order by created_at. How can I get all a users Topics and Comments combined and ordered by date?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Topics.joins(:comments).where("comments.user_id=?",current_user.id).uniq
```

It will return all the topics where current user has commented.